# BackgroungImageLayout errors

Tags: c#, winforms, button

i am creating a buttons with a default proper except for `FlatStyle = 0, BorderSize = 0, MouseDownBackColor = Transparent, MouseOverBackColor = Transparent, BackgroundImageLayout = Stretch`

using events i created `MouseEnter` with a syntax of

```
private void SearchBorrowerbutton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SearchBorrowerbutton.Image = Properties.Resources.ButtonsShinnig;

    }
```

and `MouseLeave` with a syntax of

```
private void SearchBorrowerbutton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchBorrowerbutton.Image = Properties.Resources.Buttons;
    }
```

now my problem is that whenever my mouse is pointed to the `SearchBorrowerbutton` the image change but it is not on `Stretch property` i already tried this one

```
private void SearchBorrowerbutton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchBorrowerbutton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        SearchBorrowerbutton.Image = Properties.Resources.ButtonsShinnig;

    }
private void SearchBorrowerbutton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SearchBorrowerbutton.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        SearchBorrowerbutton.Image = Properties.Resources.Buttons;
    }
```

but still it display on Tile property

Comment: what i mean on creating is that (dragging buttons from toolbox not creating a custom button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `BackgroundImageLayout` is applied only on `BackgroundImage` but you toggle the `Image` of your `Button` in your code on `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events. The solution is change `Image` to `BackgroundImage`:

```
private void SearchBorrowerbutton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchBorrowerbutton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.ButtonsShinnig;

}
private void SearchBorrowerbutton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchBorrowerbutton.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Buttons;
}
```

Comment: oh isee :) tnx for that